# How to add a variable amount of 0's to beginning of two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df:

```
    ZIP_CODE    PO_NAME STATE ZCTA
1      501 Holtsville    NY   11742
2      544 Holtsville    NY   11742
3      601   Adjuntas    PR   601
4      602     Aguada    PR   602
5      1002   Boston     MA   1002
6      90210 Los Angeles CA   90210
```

I would like to make to make the ZIP codes and the ZCTA column five digits by adding zeroes in front of the current values if they are 3 or 4 digits. For example, 501 would become 00501. How is this done?

Output:

```
    ZIP_CODE    PO_NAME STATE ZCTA
1      00501 Holtsville    NY   11742
2      00544 Holtsville    NY   11742
3      00601   Adjuntas    PR   00601
4      00602     Aguada    PR   00602
5      01002    Boston     MA   01002
6      90210   Los Angeles CA   90210
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sprintf` (assuming the columns are numeric)

```
df1$ZIP_CODE <- sprintf("%05d", df1$ZIP_CODE)
df1$ZCTA <- sprintf("%05d", df1$ZCTA)
```

---

Or doing this in a single step

```
df1[c("ZIP_CODE", "ZCTA")] <- lapply(df1[c("ZIP_CODE", "ZCTA")], 
           sprintf, fmt = "%05d")
```

---

Or in `tidyverse/stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ZIP_CODE, ZCTA), str_pad, width = 5, pad = '0')
#  ZIP_CODE     PO_NAME STATE  ZCTA
#1    00501  Holtsville    NY 11742
#2    00544  Holtsville    NY 11742
#3    00601    Adjuntas    PR 00601
#4    00602      Aguada    PR 00602
#5    01002      Boston    MA 01002
#6    90210 Los Angeles    CA 90210
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ZIP_CODE = c(501L, 544L, 601L, 602L, 1002L, 90210L
), PO_NAME = c("Holtsville", "Holtsville", "Adjuntas", "Aguada", 
"Boston", "Los Angeles"), STATE = c("NY", "NY", "PR", "PR", "MA", 
"CA"), ZCTA = c(11742L, 11742L, 601L, 602L, 1002L, 90210L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stringr::str_pad`:

```r
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(ZIP_CODE = str_pad(ZIP_CODE, 5, pad = "0", side = "left"),
              ZCTA = str_pad(ZCTA, 5, pad = "0", side = "left"))
```